# Wrong generic overload used for dynamic invocation

Tags: c#, dynamic

I am trying to implement something similar to Python's `in` operator in C# for tuples to use with `dynamic`.

Here's the sample:

```
using System;

public static class Test {
    static bool In<T>(T value, Tuple<T> a) => value.Equals(a.Item1);
    static bool In<T>(T value, Tuple<T, T> a) => value.Equals(a.Item1) || value.Equals(a.Item2);

    static void Main() {
        dynamic i = 0;
        In(i, (i, i));
    }
}
```

Surprisingly to me, that fails with

*An unhandled exception of type `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException` occurred in System.Core.dll
The best overloaded method match for `Test.In<int>(int, System.Tuple<int>)` has some invalid arguments*

I'd like to understand why C# ends up picking the first overload over the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. `(i, i)` is actually an instance of `System.ValueTuple<dynamic, dynamic>`. I just had to add overloads for `ValueTuple`. Not a `dynamic`-related issue.